# Why this PHP code not working through XAMPP?

Tags: php, xampp

No matter what Bengali number I provide in `$ben_num` variable, it always outputs 1, like with `1111111111`. Whatever the length of the `$ben_num` the output is the same length of ones (1s).

I tried to run the code in

1. [WriteCodeOnline](http://www.writephponline.com/)
2. [PHPTester](http://phptester.net/)

It works perfectly fine in these sites. Output is whatever bengali number of strings I give (eg 1234567890).

Might PHP version be the problem?

```
$ben_num = "১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯০";
bn2enNumber($ben_num);

function bn2enNumber ($number){
   $search_array= array("১", "২", "৩", "৪", "৫", "৬", "৭", "৮", "৯", "০");
   $replace_array= array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0");
   $en_number = str_replace($search_array, $replace_array, $number);

   echo $en_number;
}
```

Comment: The encoding of the PHP file is probably wrong. Try to use your code editor to change the file's encoding to UTF-8

Comment: Most likely your setup does not support multi byte strings. You want to read about that extension: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php

Comment: coderodour - Yes working fine

Comment: Nick J - Yes my code editor is in UTF-8

Comment: what is your local PHP version?

Comment: @rowmoin PHP version doesn't matter: https://3v4l.org/LD9G1

Comment: @rowmoin version doesn't matter, I tried it on the website with lowest version. It works fine.

Comment: So why @Md.IrfanOmee asked in your question that you have a concern about PHP version? By the way, could you please try to other things where you replace not Bangla try to replace English then you can find out what happened.

Comment: @rowmin as somebody mentioned about version, I tried it on lower version and told you guyz the result.

Comment: OK Guyz, Problem is solved by the guy down here v  #Xuan_Thu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your source code file (.php file) is saved in UTF-8